# Issue finding xpath that contains certain class (python, selenium, chromedriver)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find the element boxed in red below. Since this particular element's info changes, I am using the class highlighted above class = "_2z6nI" to refer to the element boxed in red, as the location of that class and its relationship to the element I am trying to press remain constant.

[image]

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body//div[contains(@class,'_2z6nI')]*how do I define additional divisions here?*)).click()
```

Would appreciate an explanation on how to determine the additional path that needs to be written after [contains(@class,'_2z6nI')] to get to the red boxed element. For reference the element I am trying to click is an Instagram user's first post on the user's home page.

Updated:

Some testable code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class bot:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("path here")

    def zoom(self, new_zoom):
        """
        :param new_zoom: zoom level as a percentage
        """
        change_js = """
        var selectBox = document.querySelector("settings-ui").shadowRoot.querySelector("#main").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-basic-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-appearance-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("#zoomLevel");

        var changeEvent = new Event("change");

        selectBox.value = arguments[0];
        selectBox.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
        """

        self.driver.get("chrome://settings/")
        new_zoom = round(new_zoom / 100, 2)
        self.driver.execute_script(change_js, new_zoom)

    def accessPlayerProfile(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/zuck/")
        time.sleep(2)
        #click on first post
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[contains(@class,'Nnq7C weEfm')])[1]"))).click()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = bot()
    bot.zoom(80)
    bot.accessPlayerProfile()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you missed space before underscore char and you aare trying to navigation child div so you can refer below solution

```
//body//div[contains(@class,' _2z6nI')]//article//div//div//div/div
```

You can also use below xpath : (**updated**)

```
  (//div[contains(@class,'Nnq7C weEfm')])[1]
```

**Working solution of your problem**

```
 element= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body//div[contains(@class,'_2z6nI')]//div//div//div[1]//div[1]//a[1]//div[1]//div[2]")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body//div[contains(@class,' _2z6nI')]//article//div//div//div/div"))).click() is not working either. I don't understand why, because after inspecting multiple pages and the relationship of the class to the element I want to select the structure is the same: go down 1 article and 4 division to reach the element.

Comment: Have you tried with remaining two ? if so make sure your _2z6nI & ySB3v class namesare not dynamic

Comment: Yes I also tried the second one. _2z6nl is constant, so unsure of why 1 or 2 won't work. But ySB3v is dynamic so the 3rd one won't work.

Comment: I tried this as well before, but it is not working either, I have copied a portion of my code above that is testable. My code involves zooming out 80% in chrome, but even after the zoom, the element I want to click and its relationship with class _2zq7c and Nnq7c appear to stay the same.

Comment: xpath was not a issue ,  please refer updated section for resolution